# Swipe right gesture with 'finger control'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode9-beta

I'm currently learning the very basics of Swift, having just finished the [iOS Application Development Tutorial from the Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html).

I am wanting to create a swipe gesture that's very similar to most popular applications that are out at the moment. Swipe right to reveal the content from another view from the left, essentially a 'back' button but with a gesture instead.

Here is an image I found of the gesture I want to create: [image: gesture]

The tutorial from Apple explains how the cancel button works in the navigation controller:

```
    //MARK: Navigation

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController {
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The MealViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }
}
```

And so (referencing the tutorial from Apple) I placed a **Swipe Gesture Recogniser** object on the 'New Meal' controller and created my own 'rightSwipe' function that does the exact same thing:

```
    @IBAction func rightSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController {
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The MealViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }

}
```

This works great, the application at the moment is clever enough to recognise your 'entry' to the view (whether it's via tapping on an existing item on the list or via the 'create a new item' view).

Is it now possible to control the animation with your finger instead of executing the entire thing as soon as the screen has been swiped to the right? This is a little difficult to explain...

As soon as I swipe right, the animation gets executed and the current view is dismissed. I have no control over the animation until it is over. I'm not able to animate the 'dismissal' with my finger as I drag it across the screen.

The scenario I want to explain is very similar to how switching pages on the home screen of iOS works.

I want to be able to 'hold' the screen on the left, be able to drag it to the right, while holding down, and should be able to see the previous view as I do it, then execute the actual transition of views as soon as I let go. I hope you understand what I mean?

How can this be achieved? Is there anything currently built in that allows me to do this? Would anyone be able to show me how this can be done?

I'm currently working with Swift 3 and using the Xcode9-beta IDE

Comment: You should get this swipe behaviour for free when you push view controllers on the navigation stack. My yesterday's answer was too quick, that's why I've deleted it. Please explain why the default iOS behaviour isn't working/good-enough for you.

Comment: Taken from the question itself: "As soon as I swipe right, the animation gets executed and the current view is dismissed. I have no control over the animation until it is over. I'm not able to animate the 'dismissal' with my finger as I drag it across the screen.

The scenario I want to explain is very similar to how switching pages on the home screen of iOS works."

Comment: I get it now. You get this effect from iOS of course when you **drag** starting from the left edge of the screen.  I just tried my earlier suggestion, but that doesn't work because the view below won't show up; you just see a white background. Also, you won't have the transparency animations that iOS does on the navigation bar, so it would also have look really bad if it did work. I conclude that you can't/shouldn't do this. You'd have to use a custom navigation stack (you may find some [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com)). You can waste a lot of time trying to make custom stuff.